# c++ qt add image to anonymous label (or other widget)

Tags: c++, qt

Hi I am working on a c++ QT project and was thinking is there a way and if there is what would be the correct syntax to call on methods of a new anonymous object so I could use temporary object like this.

```
show_area_layout->addWidget((new QLabel("",this).setPixmap(new QPixmap("./images/h1.png"))));
```

(Not a working example, but the idea should be clear) I would like for a process to generate objects to show as needed and then before attaching them to a layout change their attributes frex. adding an image to this label.
Could it somehow be possible to do in a one-liner like I tried there. Or do I have to stick these objects into some container etc. to call setPixmap or change/edit other attributes before doing something on them?

Comment: Wht you are afraid to write multiline code? Why you don't want to declare variables?

Comment: I do not want to declare variables because the process might generate N amount of labels  (from 1 to 100). So I'd declare N variables so I could present them all? More of thinking on anonymous temporary variables myself.

Comment: But you're probably right I could do it in a code block declare some local variables there I think.

Comment: There are no problems with it - your variables are created on stack. Don't optimize something before you really need optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach would only work if `setPixmap` returned the object it works on. Some classes, such as the stream operators, do this, but generally it's not a valid thing to expect.

It's not even necessary to pass the parent to the label. It'll be set when you add it to the layout, as long as the layout is set on a widget.

Here's what you could do:

```
// C++11 - local function
// Assumes that show_area_layout is already set on this   
void Class::method() {
  auto newLabel = [](const char * path) -> QLabel * {
    auto label = new QLabel();
    label->setPixmap(QPixmap(path);
    return label;
  }
  ...
  show_area_layout->addWidget(newLabel("./images/h1.png"));
  show_area_layout->addWidget(newLabel("./images/h2.png"));
  ...
}

// C++11 - single-use local function
// Assumes that show_area_layout is *not* set on this yet
void Class::method() {
  ...
  show_area_layout->addWidget([this]() -> QLabel * {
    auto label = new QLabel(this);
    label->setPixmap(QPixmap("./images/h1.png"));
    return label;
  }());
  ...
}

// C++98 - the function has to be non-local
static QLabel * newPixmapLabel(const char * path, QWidget * parent = 0) {
  QLabel * label = new QLabel(parent);
  label->setPixmap(QPixmap(path));
  return label;
}

void Class::method() {
  ...
  show_area_layout->addWidget(newPixmapLabel("./images/h1.png"));
  show_area_layout->addWidget(newPixmapLabel("./images/h2.png"));
  ...
}
```

Comment: Ahh! thank you! the C++11 lambdas can really make life easier. Have to think more on/in them.